# How do I make pseudo element :before stay active?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently struggling to make my psuedo element :before stay active when clicked.

I've made a small demo of what I have here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ud8p2nak/1/

I want it to stay active when you're on the current page, so if I'm on the accounts page I want my pseudo element to stay active on the Accounts page. I've tried with :active but that doesn't stay active fully. I'd appreciate the help, thank you.

```
<div class="side_col">

    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Accounts
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Newsletter
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Operator
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Invoice
      </div>
    </a>
```

```
.side_col {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #343A47;
}

.side_link:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #343A47;
}

.side_link:active::before {
  background-color: #24BDE9;
}

.side_link {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #343A47;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.side_link:hover {
  background-color: #2b303b;
}

.side_link_active {
  background-color: #2b303b;
}
```

Comment: a:target might help you

Comment: Thank you @IlyaNovojilov that method seemed to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

OP asked if it was possible to use `:target` with an additional `<a>` wrapped around it. Yes it is, see this test and click the last link named 'Invoice'.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/o4j5q2ng/2/)

A CSS solution is using [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class. It's easy:

1. Assign an id to the element you intend to change states (on, off, active, inactive, etc.), which will be refered to as the target.
2. Next, make an `<a>`nchor and assign it's `href` value to the target's id preceded by a `#` hashmark (ex. `<a href='#idOfTarget'>LINK</a>`).
3. Lastly, create a CSS ruleset with the target and `:target` pseudo-class (ex. `#idOfTarget:target { color: red; }`.

#### SNIPPET

```css
.side_col {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #343A47;
}
.side_link:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #343A47;
}
#sl1:target:before,
#sl2:target:before,
#sl3:target:before,
#sl4:target:before {
  background-color: #24BDE9;
}
.side_link {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #343A47;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.side_link:hover {
  background-color: #2b303b;
}
```

```html
<div class="side_col">

  <a href="#sl1">
    <div id="sl1" class="side_link">Accounts
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#sl2">
    <div id="sl2" class="side_link">Newsletter
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#sl3">
    <div id="sl3" class="side_link">Operator
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#sl4">
    <div id="sl4" class="side_link">Invoice
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it, but can I add a url to the href and still keep the id link? Or would I have to wrap the href link with another href link?

Comment: I see, you want the sidenav to be a marker as the user navigates through the site. I don't see why that wouldn't work, it seems reasonable... I'll test your theory real quick, standby.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a perfect answer, I appreciate the time you took to help me solve this problem. Works like a charm! @zer00ne

Comment: Glad to be of help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` pseudo class is a state of a link. It is applied when the mouse button is being held down. You can't use it to refer to the active page.

To solve your problem, you should write a small script to apply a unique identifier (an ID or a class name) to the link. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Nekomajin42/emajn64f/5/

Pay attention to the modified HTML and CSS! The JS is the following:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    var activepage = location.pathname;
    document.getElementById(activepage).classList.add("active");
});
```

**How it works**

Let's say your page is `example.com`! When you click on the first link in the navbar, you go to `example.com/accounts`.

When your page is loaded, the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired, which calls the function inside the event listener. You get the current subpage from the URL (`location.pathname`), then look for an element in the DOM which has the same string as an ID. If you find it, you assign the `.active` class, and the CSS will do the rest.

*Please note, that the JS code won't work in the fiddle, since you don't actually load a page, but it will be fine if you use it in your source code.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra class to the `div` you want the `::before` to be active. you can't apply `:active` like as you used. I mean you can apply `:active` but in your case it won't work, as when you click another element in the DOM it is then inactive.

You have to do it like this

```css
.side_col {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #343A47;
}
.side_link{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:30px;
}
.side_link:before {
  float: left;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 7px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: #333;
  position:absolute;
}

.side_link.active::before {
  background-color: #24BDE9;
}

.side_link {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #343A47;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.side_link:hover {
  background-color: #2b303b;
}
```

```html
<div class="side_col">

    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Accounts
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link active">Newsletter
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Operator
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="side_link">Invoice
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
```